# lateinit property has not been initialized I can not find a way to Initialize it

Tags: android, kotlin

I have lateinit property in my Kotlin activity, this is simplified version of that:

```
class CreateNewListOfQuestions : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var questionAnswerListOfObjects: ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_list_of_questions)

        save.setOnClickListener {
            questionAnswerListOfObjects.add(0, QuestionAnswerObject("question", "answer", 1))
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that when I generate mobile app and press “Save” button app stops working.
Logcat shows this error: “lateinit property questionAnswerListOfObjects has not been initialized”

I was trying many ways to initialize it but these ways did not help to me. How should I properly initialize it?
I am plining to add to ArrayList many objects of this class:

```
class QuestionAnswerObject(var question: String, var answer: String, var probability: Int=100) {}
```

Comment: Assign an object to it before the click listener is called the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what you want.

For example if everything you need is using `ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject>` you dont need `lateinit` at all:

```
var questionAnswerListOfObjects = ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject>()
```

would be enough

If you want to get from `Bundle` or from something else - you must initialize it **before** using.

Basically `lateinit` keyword is used only to say "hey, compiler, I have a variable, it is not initialized yet, but I promise it will be initialized before I use it, so please mark it as not nullable field".

So if you really want to use `lateinit`, just init that property earlier, for example add after `setContentView`

```
questionAnswerListOfObjects = ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject>()
```

Comment: Thank you! It was perfect solution! :)